# DynamoDB Auto-increment

Tags: python, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Since DynamoDB does not natively support **sequential auto-increment** for "user_id" like MySQL; what's the best way to increment the "user_id" to the next in sequence?

I'm querying the latest "user_id" and incrementing it; however, this feels pretty lame.

Is there a better way? :-)

```
def get_latest_user_id():
    try:
        # Scan the table to find the highest user_id
        response = table.scan(
            ProjectionExpression="user_id",
            FilterExpression=Attr("user_id").gt(0),
            Limit=1,
            ScanIndexForward=False  # Sort in descending order
        )
        items = response.get('Items', [])
        if not items:
            return 0  # Return 0 if table is empty
        return max(item['user_id'] for item in items)
    except ClientError as e:
        logger.error(f"Error getting latest user ID: {e}")
        raise
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Unexpected error: {e}")
        raise
```

Comment: Sequential numbers for record IDs [aren't a great pattern](https://dev.to/pazvanti/exposing-sequential-ids-is-bad-here-is-how-to-avoid-it-1mjp) for sharded databases or for privacy in general. Consider other options such as a UUID, ULID.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways in which you can do this.

1. Use an atomic counter

The first approach to generating an ever-increasing sequence number uses an atomic counter. It’s a two-step process. First, make a request to increment the counter and receive the new value in the response. Second, use that new value in a subsequent write.

```py
table = boto3.resource('dynamodb').Table('orders')

# Add one to the counter and ask for the new value to be returned
response = table.update_item(
    Key={'pk': 'orderCounter'},
    UpdateExpression="ADD #cnt :val",
    ExpressionAttributeNames={'#cnt': 'count'},
    ExpressionAttributeValues={':val': 1},
    ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
)

# Retrieve the new value
nextOrderId = response['Attributes']['count']

# Use the new value
table.put_item(
    Item={'pk': str(nextOrderId), 'deliveryMethod' : 'expedited'}
)
```

There are no race conditions with this design because all writes to a single item in DynamoDB are applied serially. This ensures that each counter value will never be returned more than once.

The cost of this approach is 1 write to update the counter item, plus the usual write costs to store the new item. The maximum throughput of this approach is limited by the counter item. The maximum throughput for a single small item in DynamoDB is the same as the maximum throughput for a partition.

1. Use Sort Key:

The second approach uses the maximum value of the sort key within an
item collection to track the maximum sequence value for that item
collection.

Items stored in a DynamoDB table can have a partition key and an optional sort key as part of their primary key. Items in an item collection have the same partition key but different sort keys. A DynamoDB query can target an item collection to retrieve all items in the collection, or can provide a sort key condition to retrieve a subset.

By designing the sort key to represent the item’s value in a sequence, it’s efficient to use a query to retrieve the maximum value of the sequence.

```py
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key

PROJECT_ID = 'projectA'

dynamo = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
client = dynamo.Table('projects')
highestIssueId = 0
saved = False

# Query for the last sorted value in the given item collection
response = client.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('pk').eq(PROJECT_ID),
    ScanIndexForward=False,
    Limit=1
)

# Retrieve the sort key value
if response['Count'] > 0:
    highestIssueId = int(response['Items'][0]['sk'])

while not saved:
    try:
        # Write using the next value in the sequence, but only if the item doesn’t exist
        response = client.put_item(
            Item={
                'pk': PROJECT_ID, 
                'sk' : highestIssueId + 1, 
                'priority' : 'low'
            },
            ConditionExpression='attribute_not_exists(pk)'
        )
        saved = True
    # An exception indicates we lost a race condition, so increment the value and loop again
    except dynamo.meta.client.exceptions.ConditionalCheckFailedException as e:
         highestIssueId = highestIssueId + 1
```

Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/implement-auto-increment-with-amazon-dynamodb/